# Node.js - Discord.js - Trying to navigate through a nested map. - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise, discord.js

I've got a map, more specifically a Discord.Collection (which extends the normal javascript Map). The keys in that collection are the server id's the bot is part of. I want the values to be a list of other things, in my case a list of commands that should be blocked from use.

The values are in a map of themselves too, the console output of the nested maps is as follows:

```js
Collection(1) [Map] {
  '267975491477176321' => Promise {
    Collection(2) [Map] {
      'music' => 'music',
      'roll' => 'roll'
    }
  }
}
```

How do I navigate through the second map in order to manipulate its values or grab them?
With

```js
bot.bannedCmds.get(`${serverID}`)
```

I can easily grab the specific key of the first map.

The result:

```js
Promise {
  Collection(2) [Map] { 'music' => 'music', 'roll' => 'roll' }
}
```

But now when I try to, for example, do this:

```js
if(bot.bannedCmds.get(`${serverID}`).has(`music`))
```

I get the error:
`(node:28288) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: bot.bannedCmds.get(...).has is not a function`

How do I work with this? Shouldn't the functions be available seeing how it is a Collection (Map) too? Or is that because it is within a Promise?

The function which fills the `bot.bannedCmds` Collection is:

```js
exports.getBannedCmds = async function (serverID){
  try{
    let bannedCmds = new Discord.Collection();
    let fetchBannedCmdsQuery = `SELECT * FROM bannedcmds WHERE serverID = '${serverID}'`;
    let fetchBannedCmds = await db.query(fetchBannedCmdsQuery, function(err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      let BlacklistTable = Object.assign(result);

      for (var cmd in BlacklistTable) {
        bannedCmds.set(`${BlacklistTable[cmd].cmd}`, `${BlacklistTable[cmd].cmd}`);
      }
    });
    return bannedCmds;
  } catch(error){
    console.trace(error);
  }
}
```

The function gets called inside the 'ready' event of the bot, in my main.js.

```js
bot.bannedCmds.set(guild.id, TestFramework.getBannedCmds(guild.id));
```

Comment: Have you tried `bot.bannedCmds.get(serverId).then(result => result.has("music"))`?

Comment: That works, not exactly like that, but I had to properly resolve the promise by myself. I assumed it was resolved already, because the documentation states that you have no need of .then() anymore when working with async / await

Comment: I don’t see in your code snippet where you’re `await`ing `bot.bannedCmds.get(serverId)`, so if you include that code snippet in your code perhaps I’d be able to help.

Comment: Also, looks like you `await`ing `db.query` but looks like it’s a callback-style function, and not a `Promise`, so this would be incorrect. If you want to use `await` with that call you have to turn `db.query` into a `Promise`.